# Retrofit best practice for PATCHing single fields

Tags: android, http, retrofit, retrofit2, patch

What is the most common and appropriate way to update single fields of a JSON resource with a `PATCH` request in Retrofit?

I see 3 ways of doing it:

1. Using `@Body` to send the full object, while leaving fields that are not supposed to be updated as `null`, so GSON will drop them:

   ```
   @PATCH("posts/{id}")
   Call<Post> patchPost(@Path("id") int id, @Body Post post);
   ```
2. Using `@FormUrlEncoded` and only pass the fields that are supposed to be updated, for example with a `@FieldMap`.

   ```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @PATCH("posts/{id}")
   Call<Post> patchPost(@Path("id") int id, @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
   ```
3. Defining a custom model class that only contains fields that are supposed to be updated, so we don't have to set anything to `null`.

   ```
   @PATCH("posts/{id}")
   Call<Post> patchPost(@Path("id") int id, @Body PostUpdate postUpdate);
   ```

Am I missing other ways? Which one is the most commonly used?

Comment: I am watching your tutorial and have the same questions. LOL

Answer (score 0):

I generally use JSON with RequestBody(Okhttp). JSON object includes just relevant fields. And then I convert it RequestBody. It's like below:

```
@PATCH(RestConstants.POST_EMPTY)
Call<EmptyResponseModel> postEmpty(@Body RequestBody body);


MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, json.toString()));
```